# Saber si un comando funciono o no con python con try y except

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo un programa con la libreria subprocess con python3, la idea es hacer un comando ssh hacia un servidor necesito capturar el resultado si falla o no, estoy intentandolo con try y except pero no tengo mucha idea, todo esto esta en una funcion:

```
try:
        proceso=Popen(['sshpass','-p', '{contra}','ssh','root@{mip}'],stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)

        #if proceso == False:
        conectat = True
        CrearWidgets()
   
        VerificacioLabel.configure(text = "Connectat")
    except proceso as e:
        VerificacioLabel.configure(text = "No s'ha trobat el servidor")
        conectat = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando atrapas excepciones, no debes agarrar la variable en la que se causó el error, sino el error mismo (puede bien ser, por ejemplo `IOError`, `TypeError`, etc. por nombrar unos cuantos). El más genérico sería `Exception`, esto te permite atrapar todo tipo de errores, aunque no es muy recomendado (a lo mejor se te escapa algún tipo de error y se te malogra todo el programa). La forma en la que lo incorporarías a tu código sería la siguiente:

```
try:
    ... # tu código
except Exception as e:
    VerificacioLabel.configure(text = "No s'ha trobat el servidor")
    conectat = False
```

De todas formas verás que **no funciona**. Esto se debe a que la conexión `ssh` se maneja en un *subproceso*, es decir, fuera del entorno de Python. Ahora, para manejar errores, tienes 2 opciones (y una que se me ocurre pero no sé qué tan práctica sea):

**1. Manejas tu código con un [wrapper](https://pypi.org/project/sshpass-wrapper/), en lugar de un subproceso**

Esto en teoría te debería permitir manejar el proceso directamente desde Python, te va a lanzar excepciones fáciles de entender y es lo más "nativo", por así decirlo. Claro, requiere una reescritura completa de todo lo que sea ssh que uses en tu programa, por lo que tal vez no sea lo que quieres.

**2. Lees el contenido que te bota la terminal de tu ssh**

Una solución que me parece un tanto compleja, pero sería leer cada línea que te da el comando que envías a tu terminal, y en base al texto que te aparezca, decides si es correcto o incorrecto. Un ejemplo muy básico puede ser algo así:

```
texto = proceso.read()
if "error" in texto:
    conectat = False
else:
    conectat = True
```

**3. (Bonus) Hacer la llamada a ssh en un script (.bat para Windows, .sh para Bash) y lanzar el error para que Python lo lea**

No sé qué tan posible sea esto debido a que no conozco el software que usas, pero a lo mejor podrías poner condiciones `IF .. ELSE` en un script en el que llamas al `sshpass`, y si ocurre la condición de error, haces que retorne algún código que tu Python puede leer.